# How to rename file java ?

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to rename files in a folder. But instead all of them get deleted

```
File thisFolder = new File("C:\\ . . . ");  
        File [] filesArray = thisFolder.listFiles();          

        int filesArrayLength = filesArray.length; 
        if (filesArray != null) { 
             for (int i = 0; i < filesArrayLength; i++) { 
                filesArray[i].renameTo(new File("test" + i + ".pdf"));  
             } 
        }
```

What am i doing wrong ? Why do all of the files get deleted instead of renamed

Comment: Are you sure there ware deleted? It looks like `new File("test" + i + ".pdf")` will rather be moved to current location from which you are running this code since you used relative path. To see which location is it print absolute path of location created with `new File(".")`.

Comment: You should probably use the `java.nio` API aswell, as the old API is terrible are error reporting. In your case, for example, [`File.renameTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) returns a `boolean` indicating success - which you ignore.

Comment: Thank you that was a relative path issue

Comment: @Melinda just because you fixed the immediate issue don't ignore my comment. It **will** come back to bite you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pshemo pointed out you might be moving the file to the current directory. Try doing this instead. This will tell it to create the file under the given parent directory:

```
filesArray[i].renameTo(new File(thisFolder, "test" + i + ".pdf"));//thisFolder is your parent directory
```

Answer (score 2):

String  strFilePath= "C:/Users/";

```
public void renameFile(String strOldFileName, String strNewFileName) {
    File oldName = new File(strFilePath + "/" + strOldFileName);
    File newName = new File(strFilePath + "/" + strNewFileName);
    if (oldName.renameTo(newName)) {
        System.out.println("renamed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code example for you to rename the List of files in a given directory as below, 
Suppose C:\Test\FileToRename isthe folder, the files which are listed under that has been renamed to test1.pdf,test2.pdf... etc..

```
File folder = new File("\\Test\\FileToRename");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {

                File f = new File("c:\\Test\\FileToRename\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName()); 

                f.renameTo(new File("c:\\Test\\FileToRename\\"+"test"+i+".pdf"));
            }
        }
```